# Exponential Stability in Lyapunov Razumikhin Theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions, delay-differential-equations

Is there an exponential stability version of the Lyapunov-Razumikhin Theorem for retarded functional differential equations? i.e. analogous to ODEs, given a FDE $\dot{x}(t)=f(x_t)$ does the following imply global exponential stability?

For a positive definite $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^+$ with $c_1||x||^p\leq V(x)\leq c_2||x||^p$ it holds,
$$\dot{V}(x_t) \leq -\alpha V(x(t)), \quad\text{if } V(x(t+\theta))\leq \beta V(x(t)) \quad\forall \theta \in [-\tau,0], \quad \text{where }\alpha>0, \beta>1.$$
Where $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_t(\cdot)= x(t+\cdot)\in \mathcal{C}\left([-\tau,0]\right)$.

Comment: Not your assumptions since they are never satisfied (except with $V=0$), but the usual ones with $x(t)$ replaced by the solution on the phase space. Nothing changes.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks a lot for your answer! What do you mean exactly by replacing $x(t)$ by the solution on the phase space? And would you know a source for the proof of this?

Comment: As I wrote, "Nothing changes", so you just need to follow the usual proof. The phase space is also the usual one, used for all delay equations.

Comment: Wouldn't this be Lyapunov-Krasovskii approach?

Comment: Since you already know it, why are your asking about it?

Comment: I asked because the literature I looked at did only look at global asymptotic stability and I could not find the theorems for exponential stability. 
Furthermore, I asked about Razumikhin and not Krasovskii functionals. But I guess with $\bar{V}(x_t) = \max_{t\in[-\tau,0]} V(x(t))$ we can reduce it to Krasovskii's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in it: The answer to my above question is yes and a proof can be found [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8133613). Furthermore, the rate of decay is at least $$\gamma = \min\left(\alpha, \log( \beta)/\tau\right)/p.$$

However, the proof is quite a lot more complicated as for ODEs or Krasovskii functionals.